# What happens if I use `takePersistableUriPermission` for files stored in the cloud but cached locally?

Tags: android, cloud, storage, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Basically, I'm trying to let users choose pictures from their phone's image gallery to use as background images in my app.

I'm considering using `takePersistableUriPermission`. I'm wondering how this works with files that are cached locally, but exist on a remote server.

For example, the Google Photos app permanently stores photos in the cloud but some of those photos are available locally on the device (cached). If a user selects a recent photo, I gain access to it via `takePersistableUriPermission`, great! Time goes by and that photo is not so recent anymore and Google Photos removes it locally. Do I still have access to it?

**Update:**

I just learned that the [number of persistable uri's your app can have is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71100621/599535).

> [For a long time, it was 128](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149315521). Android 11 raised it to 512, and it seems to be 512 for Android 12 as well.

You can and should release uri permissions you no longer need like so:

```
final int releaseFlags = intent.getFlags()
        & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

getContentResolver().releasePersistableUriPermission(fileUri, releaseFlags);
```

**Update 2:**

It's also possible for the app that owns the uri to revoke permission for that uri via `revokeUriPermission`.